startActivityForResult with RESULT_OK does not work also its not picking up the resultCode from onBackPressed()
I have 2 Activities to explain the scenario
Activity B - Has back button and when I press the back button I go back to Activity A
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("Title", "Sending the title back to MainActivity");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}

where I have startActivityResult() method called but its always giving me resultCode = REQUEST_CANCELLED and the intent is also null
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PLAYBACK) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
            if (data != null && data.hasExtra("Title")) {
                String text = data.getStringExtra("Title");
            }
        }
    }
}

Its never coming into the onAcitivityResult method in Activity B
I tried few things in onBAckPressed() method
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("Title", "Sending the title back to MainActivity");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed() ------> Added this instead of finish()
}

Also tried adding the content of onBackPressed directly into onClickListener
    ImageButton toolBarBackButton = toolBar.findViewById(R.id.player_back_button);
            toolBarBackButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent i = new  Intent();
                i.putExtra("Title", "Sending the title back to MainActivity");
                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                super.onBackPressed();
            });


Using startActivityForResult() within a single app has been obsolete for quite some time. Please consider using more modern techniques, with a single activity and two fragments or composables for the separate screens. Note that RESULT_OK is for cases where the user does not use system BACK navigation, such as clicking a button in your UI to accept some selection.

@CommonsWare yeah I have custom back button and on that onClickListener of the button I have called onBackPressed() that is why I am updating the override onBackPressed method

"yeah I have custom back button and on that onClickListener of the button I have called onBackPressed()" -- do not do that. Instead, call setResult() and finish() directly.

I am doing that already I have added in the description above how my onBackPressed() button looks

"I am doing that already" -- I am telling you to delete onBackPressed(). Do not call onBackPressed() from your onClickListener(). Instead, in your onClickListener() method, call setResult() and finish() directly.

Unfortunately that's not working its still its not going into setActivityResult() at all

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
